# Convert list of tuples into list of slices to use with np.r_

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, slice

Working in pandas, I have created a list of tuples representing a range of rows around a given set of index points:

```
mask = df.loc[df['Illustration']=='Example'].index
idxlist = [(i-1,i+10) for i in mask]
idxlist
[(2, 13), (48, 59), (120, 131),...]
```

I want to use the values from this list of tuples as the range slice indices to call `np.r_`, which takes a list of this type:

```
df.iloc[np.r_[2:13, 48:59, 120:131,...]
```

I can pass my list of tuples through the `slice` function:

```
slicelist = [slice(*(idxlist[j])) for j in range(len(idxlist))]
```

BUT `slice` and `np.r_` are not (as far as I gather) mutually compatible.

So I'm looking for either a way to convert a list of tuples into a list of slice ranges OR a way to generate a list of slice ranges using a list comprehension, similar to what I did to make `idxslice` above. I know I can find some very unelegant ways of doing this, but I'm looking for the most pythonic way, and preferably without a loop. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [208]: alist = [(2, 13), (48, 59), (120, 131)]
```

`r_` turns a list of slices into indices, using index notation (it's actually a class instance with an `__getitem__` method. The interpreter converts the `n:m` into `slice(n,m)`, but `r_` then converts that into `arange(n,m)`.

```
In [209]: np.r_[2:13, 48:59, 120:131]
Out[209]: 
array([  2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  10,  11,  12,  48,  49,
        50,  51,  52,  53,  54,  55,  56,  57,  58, 120, 121, 122, 123,
       124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130])
```

`s_` can use the same input, but makes slice objects:

```
In [211]: np.s_[2:13, 48:59, 120:131]
Out[211]: (slice(2, 13, None), slice(48, 59, None), slice(120, 131, None))
```

which is the same as (and with the same iteration):

```
In [212]: [slice(i,j) for i,j in alist]
Out[212]: [slice(2, 13, None), slice(48, 59, None), slice(120, 131, None)]
```

replacing `slice` with `arange`:

```
In [213]: [np.arange(i,j) for i,j in alist]
Out[213]: 
[array([ 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12]),
 array([48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58]),
 array([120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130])]
```

and joining them produces the same thing as `r_`:

```
In [214]: np.hstack(_)
Out[214]: 
array([  2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  10,  11,  12,  48,  49,
        50,  51,  52,  53,  54,  55,  56,  57,  58, 120, 121, 122, 123,
       124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130])
```

`r_` is pretty, but computationally it is just the same.  There's nothing in-elegant or un-pythonic about a list comprehension like this.

Since each range has the same length (11 values), we could also use `linspace`:

```
In [220]: np.linspace((2,48,120),(13,59,131),11,endpoint=False, dtype=int)
Out[220]: 
array([[  2,  48, 120],
       [  3,  49, 121],
       [  4,  50, 122],
       [  5,  51, 123],
       [  6,  52, 124],
       [  7,  53, 125],
       [  8,  54, 126],
       [  9,  55, 127],
       [ 10,  56, 128],
       [ 11,  57, 129],
       [ 12,  58, 130]])
In [221]: np.hstack(_.T)
Out[221]: 
array([  2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  10,  11,  12,  48,  49,
        50,  51,  52,  53,  54,  55,  56,  57,  58, 120, 121, 122, 123,
       124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130])
```

You could still use `r_` and `alist` (but using `arange` is more direct):

```
In [225]: np.r_.__getitem__(tuple([slice(i,j) for i,j in alist]))
Out[225]: 
array([  2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  10,  11,  12,  48,  49,
        50,  51,  52,  53,  54,  55,  56,  57,  58, 120, 121, 122, 123,
       124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130])
```

`np.r_` is just a `concatenate` disguised as indexing (with some added bells):

```
np.r_[tuple([np.arange(i,j) for i,j in alist])]
np.hstack([np.arange(i,j) for i,j in alist])
```

Comment: Over and above the call of duty! These kind of pedagogical replies are always sincerely appreciated; thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

No need to get super fancy, since the indices follow a pattern just make a list of all of them.

```
from itertools import chain

#mask = [3, 49, 121, ...]
m = [*chain.from_iterable([range(i-1, i+10) for i in mask])]

# or simply
m = [x for i in mask for x in range(i-1, i+10)]

# Then
df.iloc[m]
```

Comment: Nice. So basically I needed to take one extra step further back and rethink it from that level. This is great, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Full numpy solution :

```py
import numpy as np    
indices = np.array(np.concatenate([np.arange(i,j) for i, j in idxlist]))
df.iloc[indices]
```

Comment: This solution makes particular sense in light of @hpaulj's explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to add a different answer, it still requires a loop but you can stack the numpy arrays gotten from unpacking the ranges.

```
np.hstack([np.fromiter(range(*i), dtype=int, count=len(range(*i))) for i in idx])
```

Answer (score 0):

I like

```
 alist = [(2, 13), (48, 59), (120, 131)]
  #print(alist)
 results=[np.arange(x[0],x[1]) for x in alist]
 print(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the tuple to slice the data

```
data=[x for x in np.arange(131)]

idxlist=[(2, 13), (48, 59), (120, 131)]
 data=[x for x in np.arange(131)]

 for tupleSlice in idxlist:
     print(data[tupleSlice[0]:tupleSlice[1]])
```